# Question about installing "apache poi" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Java 21, tried to use apache poi 5.3.2, does not work (have properly added jar file into Libraries). As I have understood, 5.3.2 does not support Java 21. My question is - how to install apache poi 5.2.5 which does not have ready jar files and I do not understand how to import files into the Library

Help to understand how to install apache poi 5.2.5 in Eclipse

Comment: "As I have undesrtood, 2.3.2...." I meant 5.3.2

Comment: you should be able to edit your question - did it now for you.

Comment: Define "does not work"

Comment: And if indeed apache-poi 5.3.2 does not support Java 21, what do you expect us to do?

Answer (score 0):

According to the section [Binary Artifacts](https://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-bin-artifacts) of Apache POIs download page, you should be able to include binaries from the central Maven repo for builds with Maven, Gradle and other build systems.

And they also provide a link there (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/) where you can manually search the Maven Central Repo for the binaries in case you want to download them directly.

For stable and reproducable builds I would recommend that you start to use a build system like [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org) and depend on that library in the proper way. This also will make your build independent from the IDE you use (in your case Eclipse), but most IDEs (and also Eclipse) provide a way to build also with such build systems.